# How to use PHP code In a Plugin's Short Code on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

The shortcode is:

```
[sp-client-document-manager uid=]
```

uid= need to display wp user id to display user files.

I am using another wp plugin (Ultimate Member) which can pull the user ID from the profile page using this code:

```
$profile_id = um_profile_id();
```

I tried this along with sever other variations:

```
[sp-client-document-manager uid=$profile_id = um_profile_id();]
```

Comment: to output the value of `um_profile_id()` you can use `<?= um_profile_id() ?>`. so you can try the following: `[sp-client-document-manager uid=<?= um_profile_id(); ?>]`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.

When I put a number it pulls the correct content.

Not sure if <?= um_profile_id(); ?> is pulling loged-in user or not?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using this shortcode in the code files or WP Editor?

Comment: I am trying both, aidinMC's suggestion did not work so far, that or I am putting in the wrong place.

Trying to get (SP Project & Document Manager) to display on the (Ultimate Member) profile page and display that user's files.

Answer (score 0):

To see `shortcode` output, You must use `do_shorcode` function , update your last line to below:

```
$profile_id = um_profile_id();
echo do_shortcode("[sp-client-document-manager uid='$profile_id']");
```

Comment: When I use <?php echo do_shortcode("[sp-client-document-manager uid=4]"); ?> it will display user profile from ID 4. When I use <?php echo do_shortcode("[sp-client-document-manager uid='$profile_id']"); ?> it pulls the admin files (or the user loged-in and not the profile I am viewing)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by using

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode("[sp-client-document-manager uid='".um_profile_id()."']"); ?>
```

Added it to bottom of templates/profile.php in the Ultilate Member plugin folder